# Is there a difference between source code and inline code?

Tags: inline

Some searches define inline code as code that's "added/ written into the body of a program."

But clearly, inline code isn't just any code you write which is also manually "added/ written into the body of your program" as you type the code into the source code files.

What is a non-ambiguous definition of inline code?

My guess is that it's lines of source code that get automatically replaced by the compiler with other instruction lines (hence in-line). However, is it the code that gets replaced or the code that replaces?

Answer (score 0):

Typically "inline" refers to functions / subroutines (I will use the terms interchangeably).

A function is typically a separate piece of code that gets "called" (or "invoked") from elsewhere, and "returns" back to the place it was called from after it is done executing. However, the "calling" and "returning" takes time. Not much time, but if a function is called very often, it adds up.

Usually a compiler will translate the "calling" and "returning" operations into comparable operations in the lower-level language (typically bytecode or machine code). However, some languages offer the option to mark a function as "inline"; the compiler will then not generate the "calling" and "returning" instructions in the lower-level language, but instead replace the "calling" instruction with the entire body of the function, to avoid the function invocation overhead. Some languages/compilers do not need the programmer to explicitly mark a function as "inline", as they can detect a frequently invoked function automatically as a part of their optimisation efforts. In a super-simplified example, with pseudocode:

Source code:

```
"Square of x" means "result of multiplication of x and x".
For each i from 1 to 10 print square of x.
For each i from 10 to 1 print square of x.
```

Translated code (unoptimised version), into a lower level language (still pseudocode):

```
"Square of x" means "result of multiplication of x and x".
Let i be 1.
While i is less or equal than 10:
    Let s be the square of x.
    Print s.
    Increment i.
Let i be 10.
While i is greater or equal than 1:
    Let s be the square of x.
    Print s.
    Decrement i.
```

Translated code (inlined version):

```
Let i be 1.
While i is less than 10:
    Let s be the result of multiplication of x and x.
    Print s.
    Increment i.
Let i be 10.
While i is greater or equal than 1:
    Let s be the result of multiplication of x and x.
    Print s.
    Decrement i.
```

In the first "translated" snippet, the execution environment must remember in each pass of the loop what "square of `x`" means. In the second "translated" snippet, "square" itself is never mentioned since it was inlined, and we don't have to waste time to figure out what it means.

Why not always inline functions, if it is faster? Because if the invocation is not in just one place, inlining bloats the size of the translated (executable) code, as you need to put in the entire function body wherever it would be invoked. Also, there are some problems where inlining cannot be done (or at least not without majorly restructuring the code), for example when the function calls itself (i.e. you would need to replace a part of the function with the whole body of the function, which is like a snake trying to swallow one's own body: not possible to do fully).

Tl;dr: For a succint definition of "inline code", my best attempt is probably "the result of replacing a function call with the function body in the process of compilation". "Source code", on the other hand, is either "code text that can be directly executed by an interpreter" or "code text that has yet to undergo compilation".

Comment: I think inline (functions) is more so lines of code that usually call subroutines (methods/ functions) and get replaced by the respective bodies of the called functions in the source code by a pre-processor before compilation. 
An inline line of code that calls a subroutine gets replaced by the called code in its line (hence in-line).
Macro functions are thus also inlined - they get replaced by the larger set of instructions they refer to by the preprocessor.

Comment: @alexbling No preprocessors that I know of deal with inline functions; for example, running `cc -E a.c` will not replace calls to inline functions, though it will replace macros.